# php function mail() isn't working

Tags: php, email, smtp

I used mail() function in php coding but I failed to send any mail. Before proceeding ahead I want to elaborate the context of using the mail() function.

I didnt host my site so it is on localhost.
I did set smtp, port sendmail_path etc.

After searching a lot I it seems that I need to download a mail server.
I downloaded a sendmail server that is free and configured it as the site suggested.
However, all in vain moreover, someone told me that I can't use mail function until I host my site not only on localhost. Please guide me.

```
<?php
   $from = "oooo@hotmail.com"; // sender
   $subject = " My cron is working";
   $message = "My first Cron  :)";

   // message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it

   $message = wordwrap($message, 70);

   // send mail

   ini_set("SMTP","localhost");
   ini_set("smtp_port","25");
   ini_set("sendmail_from","00000@gmail.com");
   ini_set("sendmail_path", "C:\wamp\bin\sendmail.exe -t");

   mail("jXXXXXX@gmail.com",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");

   echo "Thank you for sending us feedback";

?>
```

this my sendmail configuration file:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=auto

;default_domain=domain.com
auth_username=jxxxx@gmail.com
auth_password=8888

force_sender=j*****@gmail.com

( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Warning: mail() [<a href='function.mail'>function.mail</a>]: Failed to connect to      mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot;    setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 20
```

Comment: Try changing your "mail from" as google would know that you're not n ormally allowed to send email from hotmai

Comment: Try using your ISP's smtp server. They usually allow *ALL* e-mail from their clients as long as you're not spamming.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: @ferozakbar yes :( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Warning: mail() [<a href='function.mail'>function.mail</a>]: Failed to connect to      mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot;    setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 20

Comment: what have to put as your smtp server? localhost?

Comment: i put using ini_set fuction localhost

Comment: Watch out, if you are sending mail from the CLI using CRON, then you are probably picking up the PHP CLI ini file, not php.ini

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think you are not configured properly,

if you are using XAMPP then you can easily send mail from localhost.

for example you can configure `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` and `c:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini` for gmail to send mail.

in `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` find `extension=php_openssl.dll` and remove the semicolon from the beginning of that line to make SSL working for gmail for localhost.

in php.ini file find `[mail function]` and change

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = my-gmail-id@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
```

(use the above send mail path only and it will work)

Now Open `C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini`. Replace all the existing code in sendmail.ini with following code

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
auth_password=my-gmail-password
force_sender=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
```

Now you have done!! create php file with mail function and send mail from localhost.

***Update***

First, make sure you PHP installation has SSL support (look for an "openssl" section in the output from `phpinfo()`).

You can set the following settings in your PHP.ini:

```
ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","465");
```

Comment: SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.
now i am getting this message.
my setting was:

ini_set("SMTP","smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","587");
ini_set("sendmail_from","******@gmail.com");
this was my setting however when I set these settings:

Comment: yes I did check my php.ini file it support openssl, please guide what i need to do now? i already enabled IMAP on gmail

Comment: this my code:
ini_set("SMTP","sll://smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","587");
ini_set("sendmail_from","88888@gmail.com");
//ini_set("sendmail_path", "C:\wamp\bin\sendmail.exe -t");

Comment: change the port to 465

Comment: when i change the port still there is some error and it says:Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;sll://smtp.gmail.com&quot; port 465, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set(); i am accessing my file :localhost:8080/test.php

Comment: are you using wamp or xammp?

Comment: have you enabled ENABLE IMAP option in gmail settings

Comment: i am using wamp and i did enable IMAP

Comment: have you enabled the ssl_module(in apache->apache modules),php_openssl,php_sockets(in php->php extension) in wamp window?

Comment: in folder module I found file mod_ssl.so i dont know how to enable it

Comment: no if you are using wamp then you see can these options in the bottom right corner in your desktop,where you can see the wamp icon

Comment: php_openssl was already enabled but however, php_sockets were not enable. I did enable both of the options

Comment: you have to download the php_sockets.dll file and place it in extensions folder and restart the wamp.if still have problem then in your php.ini file put this extension=php_sockets.dll and restart the wamp,hope you will success :)

Comment: i recommend you should follow all these steps again.
http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-using-wamp-server/

Comment: but however there is some more troublesome issue need to be discussed. i want to send email via task scheduling on periodic base that mean i have to execute the using php.exe on cli. how can i use PHPmailer class cli?

Comment: if you want to schedule your mails on particullar time,then use crons for that.using cron jobs we can do automatic tasks as per our requiremnt.once see this http://www.jabcreations.com/blog/basic-php-cron-job-example
and if you think i am helped you then please accept this as answer so that the new people can easily find out,thanks

Comment: you can see a green tick mark just below the up and down votes at my answer

Comment: @ɹɐqʞɐzoɹǝɟ where can i paste `ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");` ? anywhere? in php.ini

Comment: no brother, init_set in an php function so you should put it in top of your php script

Answer (score 1):

I followed @ɹɐqʞɐ zoɹǝɟ solution. However, it did not fully solve my issue, I had to do one more step.

I had to turn on 'Less Secure App Access' settings from my google account settings page. After doing this I was able to send the mail.

Link to the settings page - [Less Secure App Access](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1&rapt=AEjHL4O1fF5Pwy-9Lp4uB7djq_JaEryCzrr_EtIToyJN5MTiVXRauvC9J56xdAaZ6xAsfklWp4bQOLJY2-kyqds9YS_p8u8z1Q)

I had 2-Step Verification enabled in my account and had to disable it to access the setting.

Note:
Turning on less secure app access can make your account vulnerable and is not recommended to use it in the long run. I was using a test account and not my primary account while doing this.